# X-Tika-PDFocrStrategy is an invalid X-Tika-OCR header error

Tags: apache, pdf, jax-rs, ocr, apache-tika

I am trying to use TikaJAXRS and add headers for setting PDFParser properties. Specifially the ocrStrategy property. However, when I add the header using X-Tika-PDFocrStrategy, I get an error stating that it is an invalid X-Tika-OCR header.

After looking into the source code, I believe the issue might be with the 'fillParseContext' method in the TikaResource.java file.

```
public static void fillParseContext(ParseContext parseContext, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
                                    Parser embeddedParser) {
    TesseractOCRConfig ocrConfig = new TesseractOCRConfig();
    PDFParserConfig pdfParserConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
    for (String key : httpHeaders.keySet()) {
        if (StringUtils.startsWith(key, X_TIKA_OCR_HEADER_PREFIX)) {
            processHeaderConfig(httpHeaders, ocrConfig, key, X_TIKA_OCR_HEADER_PREFIX);
        } else if (StringUtils.startsWith(key, X_TIKA_PDF_HEADER_PREFIX)) {
            processHeaderConfig(httpHeaders, pdfParserConfig, key, X_TIKA_PDF_HEADER_PREFIX);
        }
    }
    parseContext.set(TesseractOCRConfig.class, ocrConfig);
    parseContext.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfParserConfig);
    if (embeddedParser != null) {
        parseContext.set(Parser.class, embeddedParser);
    }
}
```

The if statement first looks for a key that starts with the OCR header prefix, and since the PDFParser's property name contains 'ocr', it is trying to find a property named 'ocrStrategy' in the OCRParser class, which doesn't exist.

Can anyone verify this, or tell me how I could set that property via the restful service?

Side note, I am using Tika as a service via a docker container and calling it from a python app.

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache Tika 1.13

Comment: I had tried using the "X-Tika-PDFextractInlineImages": "true" header, which did successfully find and set the property, but it wasn't ocr'ing the images. I just upgraded my docker container to a version that uses Apache Tika 1.14, and now that images are successfully being ocr'd. So this at least helps me in the mean time, but the original issue of it not being able to set the ocrStrategy (and other PDFParser properties prefixed by ocr) still exists.

Comment: Can you report a bug? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA/ - One of our PDF/OCR experts can hopefully then see this and get it fixed :)

Comment: Just added it [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2290)